# What is the meaning of the sentence referring to functions introduced by a using declaration?

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm studying the C++03 Standard and am now reading `[7.3.3]/11`, but I'm having trouble understanding the following passage:

> If a function declaration in namespace scope or block scope has the same name and the same parameter
>   types as a function introduced by a using-declaration, and the declarations do not declare the same function,
>   the program is ill-formed.

I haven't found any examples of this situation anywhere and I don't understand the meaning of this passage.

Comment: There's an example in the very standard paragraph you're citing. Can you elaborate on why that doesn't answer you?

Comment: FYI. C++11 adds some examples. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/namespace.udecl#14.

Comment: Hey! Don't forget to mark this question solved if the answers helped you!  :D

Answer (score 5):

What it means is that:

```
namespace namespace_1
{
    void foo(int number);
}
using namespace_1::foo;
void foo(int roll_no);
```

This means the program is ill-formed.
I believe it means to say that the function would be confusing to read. As at one point, the function definition would be using the passed int as an integer(general) but in the other case, we'd be using it as a roll_no.

This would also cause ambiguity in overloaded function matching.

The source you are citing gives an example just below the lines you have cited:

```
namespace B {
  void f(int);
  void f(double);
}
namespace C {
  void f(int);
  void f(double);
  void f(char);
}
void h() {
  using B::f;       // B::f(int) and B::f(double)
  using C::f;       // C::f(int), C::f(double), and C::f(char)
  f('h');           // calls C::f(char)
  f(1);             // error: ambiguous: B::f(int) or C::f(int)?
  void f(int);      // error: f(int) conflicts with C::f(int) and B::f(int)
}
```

Comment: [Some extra reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations)

Comment: The more I use C++, the less I seem to use namespaces for shortcuts, and the more I get annoyed by code that does.

Comment: using namespace blablabla is not using declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The following program contains the error

```
#include <iostream>

namespace _1{
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_1::f\n";
    }
}

namespace _2{
/*
*If a function declaration in namespace scope or block scope has the 
*same name and the same parameter types as a function introduced by
* a using-declaration
*/
    using _1::f;
// This is not the same function as introduced by the using directive
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_2::f\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    _2::f();
}
```

The diagnostic is

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int _2::f()’:
main.cpp:13:11: error: ‘int _2::f()’ conflicts with a previous declaration
     int f(){
```

As a contrast, the following program is correct. The _1 namespace is introduced via a using directive.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace _1{
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_1::f\n";
    }
}

namespace _2{
    using namespace _1;

    int f(){
        std::cout << "_2::f\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    _2::f();
}
```

With the expected  output

```
_2::f
```

As for the same situation in block scope you have

```
#include <iostream>

namespace _1{
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_1::f\n";
    }
}

namespace _2{

    int g(){
// As before but in block scope.
        using _1::f;

        int f();
        f();
    }
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_2::f\n";        
    }

}

int main(){
    _2::f();
}
```

The diagnostic is identical

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int _2::g()’:
main.cpp:15:15: error: ‘int _2::f()’ conflicts with a previous declaration
         int f();
               ^
```

The parallel construct of the successful sample above would be

```
#include <iostream>

namespace _1{
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_1::f\n";
    }
}

namespace _2{

    int g(){
        using namespace _1;

        int f();
        f();
    }
    int f(){
        std::cout << "_2::f\n";        
    }

}

int main(){
    _2::g();
}
```

With the output

```
_2::f
```

Comment: thank you for clear clarification. but what about block scope. I can't get same result on block scope.

Comment: @Pupkin See the two added samples.

Comment: Many thanks. I try to distinguish further an using declaration in namespace scope, block scope, class scope. I tested for class scope and so i was confused, but a select of scope is important for this rule.